# My wordpress site memory exhausted more than 1GB trying to debug with default

Tags: theme-development, themes, debug

My wordpress site memory is exhausted

> [02-Nov-2022 08:41:33 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 1073741824 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 262144 bytes) in /home/ahzabcollections/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-query.php on line 3726

So, After too much debugging and all that i diagnosed that my theme is crashing and when i disable theme i can easily access wp-admin otherwise i am unable to login. I think it's somekind of stuck in some loop.

Is there any way i can get call stack or trace that which function of theme is culprit and how to debug this properly in php way like stack trace.

Thanks in advance for any kind of help.

Comment: What has changed recently? If you think it's the theme, reach out to the theme's support team for support.

Comment: @PatJ Thanks for reply ... Can you please let me know how a normal person can debug wordpress that from where the call is repeating.

Answer (score 0):

i have too  problemm.

Maybe this a betheme theme use or wordpress version 6.1 ?

Yohoo... I can repair this problemm

I use Betheme 25.6.1.3 and wordpress upgrade to 6.1 version automatic...

I download version betheme 26.5.1.4, upload  on ftp in wp-content/themes/betheme zip archive and unzip to files ...

And this work!!!

See upgrade uor theme and compatibility to this Wordpress version. Or donwgrade wordpress to version 6.0.3 ! (for ftp to replacement files wordpress )

Comment: Really thankful that solved my issue but is there any way we can debug calls that how that stack is called.